# What DVI cable do I need?

Tags: display, graphics-card, dvi

The DVI cable connecting my monitor and video card is too short and there is zero slack on each end. What kind of replacement cable do I need to order? I am not familiar with all the different specifications. I do know that 10ft should be long enough.

```
        ASUS VS247 (1920x1080@60Hz)
        2047MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti (EVGA) 27 °C
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highest resolution supported by single-link DVI is 1920x1200, so you'll be fine with a "standard" single-link DVI cable. For resolutions exceeding 1920x1200, you'll need to use a dual-link DVI-D cable (much thicker, more expensive, and with more pins). DVI-I vs DVI-D does not matter in your case, since the difference pertains to the presence of both a analog and digital signal being transmitted side-by-side, whereas in your case a digital-only signal is fine.

Short answer: the cheapest DVI-D (single-link) will suffice for your resolution and needs. For future proofing, consider buying a (much, much more expensive) dual-link DVI-D cable.

Comment: Though, at higher resolutions and better displays, displayport/hdmi would end up being a more viable option. In this case single-link makes a ton of sense.

Comment: [Dual link DVI cables are cheap if you know where to buy them](http://www.monoprice.com/category?c_id=102&cp_id=10209)

Comment: @Moab thanks for the link, I didn't know you could find them at that price! Even monoprice was selling them for much more (on AMZ) when I was looking a few years back. +1

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi been buying from them for a long time, hard to beat that website for price, cables seem to be of good to high quality also.

Comment: Thanks for EasyBCD, I could not live without it, well I could but would have less hair on my head.

Comment: @Moab you're most welcome, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Check what type of cable you currently have, and then order that based off the guide below.

[image: DVI Connector Guide]

Comment: I looked at my current cable, and it appears I have DVI-D Single Link. I will just get one of those.